# Why InvalidOperationException for this code in OnNavigatedFrom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I know this exception has been mentioned many times, but I am seeing it very infrequently in Crittercism.  From all the docs I've read on the subject it seems this code is correct. Apart from what could be wrong with this code, is it ok to access State in a method call from OnNavigatedFrom? It seems unlikely to me that it matters, but the call vm.SaveStateForTombstone(State) goes through a couple method calls, but technically State is still being used inside OnNavigatedFrom, right? I don't see the exception in my Emulator or debugging the device. 
Any suggestions are appreciated!

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   You can only use State between OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.get_State()
>   1
>   at EHI.National.WP8.Common.EhiPhoneApplicationPageBase.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
>   2
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)

Here's the code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
     if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
     {
        return;     
     }
     vm.SaveStateForTombstone(State);
}
```

Comment: Is "state" inside your vm.SaveStateForTombstone used in any async method? If yes, state may no longer be appropriate to use as it runs in a different context / thread.

Comment: I have exact same problem... Cannnot find cause or solution...